# Is it possible to report NAs in stargazer table?

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

[Stargazer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/) package gives me really nice descriptive table to include in latex document.

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(attitude)
```

[image]

Is it possible to add a column reporting number of NAs for each of the variables?

Comment: I haven't seen `stargazer` tag being used in previous questions and don't have enough reputation to create it. Would it make a sense to add it?

Comment: I don't think so, but mail to the developer - I believe he will be happy to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet will give you the number of NAs per row and column in a data frame

```
# make some data
count <- 10
data <- data.frame( a=runif(count), b=runif(count))

# add some NAs
data[data$a>0.5,]$a <- NA
data[data$b>0.5,]$b <- NA

# NAs per row
data$NACount <- apply(data, 1, function(x) {length(x[is.na(x)])})

# NAs per column
NACountsByColumn <- lapply(data, function(x) {length(x[is.na(x)])} )
```

Answer (score 0):

The "N" column of stargazer does not count the NAs. Alhough there is not direct way to input NAs in the output table, you can simply calculate it by

nrow(dataset) - the number in "N" column